# automatically c++ source code formatting in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

how can I format or align with Visual Studio 2013 several c++ source codes in all projects?

Is there a opportunity for an individual template which I can use across projects?

An example with the actual code:

```
for(int i= 0; i<(n+  m) ;  i++){
}
```

An example how the desired code look like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < (n + m); i++ )
{
}
```

I use the formating with CTRL+K -> CTRL+D for the actual document and CTRL+K -> CTRL+F for the actual selection. But this doesn't satisfy my individual requirements. How can I configure this for my own requierements?

If there is not an opportunity with available tools on visual studio 2013, I will look for plugins.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999b219z(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ's link is a bit old and not applicable to your question. Try [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/08/23/c-ide-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013/) instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your link. I know how to use the basic format in VS. How I tried to explain, it doesn't satisfy my individual requierements. So I'm looking for an opportunity to create my own code formating convention.

Comment: @Cody May be I've been not looking there thoroughly enough. 1st hit on google though.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't mean the default formating settings, which i know to use. Do you know, how i can create my own code formating convention and use this as a template for all c++ source codes in all projects?

Comment: The built-in code formatting is all you get. You can obviously write your own linter if you want, but there's no hook to integrate it. You'll need to write a plug-in, and that makes this question far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: go for clang-format, check here http://llvm.org/builds/ and here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format Usually I use the first one from LLVM snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Try the AStyle plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lukamicoder.AStyleExtension

Set it to `format on save` and then `ctrl+s` becomes the format command (if you want it to format frequently).  Plus, with it using AStyle, you can [heavily customize](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) to your formatting conventions.

---

We also use a astyle config file and have a build server that periodically executes formatting on the repo.  You can do the same using a batch file:

```
:: This script can be setup to run on a daily or weekly basis to clean up code commits

:: TODO : add directories and options for formatting
astyle --options=config.astyle -r ..\..\Source\*.cpp

:: TODO : add directories and messages for committing.
svn commit -m "[AUTO] Astyle Autoformatting" ..\..\Source\
```

Where the config.astyle looks like:

```
--suffix=none # do not retain a backup of the original file

--style=allman

--indent=spaces=4
--convert-tabs

--indent-switches
--pad-oper

--align-pointer=type
--align-reference=type

--max-instatement-indent=40

--keep-one-line-blocks
--keep-one-line-statements
```

To your taste.